# How could I use Promise.all in an Async/Await function using try/catch

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to get my head around promises. So far I like using async/await and a try/catch block as it's readable for me personally.

However I'm stuck on using `Promise.all` in this.

Here is the data I'm using for practice.

```js
const starWars = [
  'https://swapi.co/api/people/1',
  'https://swapi.co/api/people/2',
  'https://swapi.co/api/people/3',
  'https://swapi.co/api/people/4'
];
```

I have the feeling I must use `.map()` within the async function however keep encountering errors.

So my question is. What is a way of fetching data from these urls using async/await, Promise.all and a try/catch block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map each URL to a `fetch` call, and call `.json` on the `fetch` Promise:

```js
const urls = [
  'https://swapi.co/api/people/1',
  'https://swapi.co/api/people/2',
  'https://swapi.co/api/people/3',
  'https://swapi.co/api/people/4'
];

(async () => {
  try {
    const allResponses = await Promise.all(
      urls.map(url => fetch(url).then(res => res.json()))
    );
    console.log(allResponses[0]);
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
    // handle errors
  }
})();
```

I'd prefer to catch outside the function, I think it looks cleaner and requires less indentation:

```js
const urls = [
  'https://swapi.co/api/people/1',
  'https://swapi.co/api/people/2',
  'https://swapi.co/api/people/3',
  'https://swapi.co/api/people/4'
];

(async () => {
  const allResponses = await Promise.all(
    urls.map(url => fetch(url).then(res => res.json()))
  );
  console.log(allResponses[0]);
  // do stuff with allResponses
})()
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log(e);
    // handle errors
  });
```

If you only have a single place where you need to wait for a Promise to resolve, you could also consider ditching the `async` function altogether (this would look even better IMO):

```js
const urls = [
  'https://swapi.co/api/people/1',
  'https://swapi.co/api/people/2',
  'https://swapi.co/api/people/3',
  'https://swapi.co/api/people/4'
];

Promise.all(
  urls.map(url => fetch(url).then(res => res.json()))
)
  .then((allResponses) => {
    console.log(allResponses[0]);
    // do stuff with allResponses
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log(e);
    // handle errors
  });
```

Comment: Why do you even bother with `async/await` here in the 2nd one and why use the IIFE? Why not just put `.then()` and `.catch()` on the promise from `Promise.all()` and have much simpler looking code?

Comment: Yeah, I don't think there's really any benefit to `async`/`await` when there's only a single place to wait, but that's what OP was trying to figure out how to implement

Answer (score 0):

You can create promises for all urls using `map` function and wait them via `Promise.all`

```
const starWars = [
  'https://swapi.co/api/people/1',
  'https://swapi.co/api/people/2',
  'https://swapi.co/api/people/3',
  'https://swapi.co/api/people/4'
]; 

const promises = starWars.map(url => fetch(url).then(res => res.json());

Promise.all(promises).then(results => /*Resolved code*/)
                     .catch(error => /*Rejected code*/);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const starWars = [
  'https://swapi.co/api/people/1',
  'https://swapi.co/api/people/2',
  'https://swapi.co/api/people/3',
  'https://swapi.co/api/people/4'
];

async function makeApiCalls() {
  try {
    let res = await Promise.all(starWars.map(endpoint => fetch(endpoint)));
    // depending on content-type apply .json() .blob() etc
    console.log(response);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue & a mentor from Discord helped me.

I believe you were running it on Windows 10 and all I did was turned off the security (in Privacy and Security settings of chrome) and it worked as expected.

**Note: Please make sure to turn this on while browsing.**